# Mail sent by Exim4 are refused by specific provider (@libero.it)

Tags: debian, email, exim

I'm a basic Linux server user. I installed my Debian VPS with patience and effort.

I'm using Exim4 to send emails. It does work properly. Tests like the following are fine:

```
echo "This is a test." | mail -s Testing someone@somedomain.com
```

but I noticed that the emails sent to a specific provider (**@libero.it** in my case) are not received. This provider uses the following configuration:

```
IMAP:
imapmail.libero.it
Port: 993 with SSL

POP:
popmail.libero.it
Port: 995 with SSL

SMTP (with SSL):
smtp.libero.it  (authentication required)
Port: 465 with SSL
```

My `update-exim4.conf.conf` file is the following:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='mindteq.com'
dc_local_interfaces=''
dc_readhost='mindteq.com'
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

and the log says:

```
2017-03-30 11:09:01 1ctbh7-0008Mg-Eb <= root@mindteq.com U=root P=local S=774
2017-03-30 11:09:01 1ctbh7-0008Mg-Eb ** enrico@libero.it <root@mindteq.com> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp: retry time not reached for any host after a long failure period
```

I also installed a TLS certificate:

```
bash /usr/share/doc/exim4-base/examples/exim-gencert
```

and added `MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = yes` to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` before he line `.ifdef MAIN_TLS_ENABLE`

but still emails to **@libero.it** are refused. Can you help me understand how to send mails to this (or these) ISP?

Comment: your problem seem with mindtec.com, as your contact state libero, but the emaill is actually at mintec.com

Comment: Is the recipient requiring DKIM setup? That has blocked email for me in the past.

Comment: Yagmoth555. What could be the problem with mindteq.com?
Jason yesterday. I dont' think the recipent needs DKIM. I did not found any information about.
I noticed that another ISP (@alice.it) refuses email by my Exim4 configuration.Maybe these ISP block smtp port 25? I tried to change the port following a number of tutorials but the problem still remains.